# How to differentiate between \chapter and \chapter* inside a fancyhead

Tags: sectioning, chapters, fancyhdr

I have a custom head in my doc based on `\documentclass{book}`

The following pages after a `\chapter` present the following pattern:

`Chapter X: title`

provide by: `\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}`

but, a bug occours when user call `\chapter*` where heading show previouly `\chapter`. There is a way to differentiate it?

**edited** with @david Carlisle suggestion.
Minimal example to reproduce the error:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\chapter*{Sumary}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Metodology}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter*{References}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Here there is a bug in the heading. Should be only 'References' or either empty.

\end{document}
```

Comment: you wouldn't normally directly access \thechapter in a heading always go indirectly via `\leftmark`  and `\rightmark` then you can arrange for `\chapter` and `\chapter*` to put whatever text you want in the marks

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i have updated the minimal code to reproduce the error. Unfortunately, the \leftmark is the same in \chapter* as previous \chapter.

Comment: sure that's what I meant you can use `\markleft{something}` after the chapter* or arrange that * versions do that automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter` and `\backmatter`.

After the first or the third commands are issued, `\chapter` will produce unnumbered chapters that will go in the table of contents. Under `\mainmatter` chapters are numbered.

You also need to modify the definition of `\chaptermark` (and I took the occasion for removing the horrible default uppercasing). However, `\tableofcontents` does `\MakeUppercase`, so `\nouppercase` is still necessary.

If you don't want Roman page numbers in the frontmatter, a simple modification to `\frontmatter` and `\mainmatter` is sufficient.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \if@mainmatter
      \chaptername\ \thechapter. %
    \fi
    #1%
  }{}%
}
% the following is to get numbering from 1 for all the document
\renewcommand{\frontmatter}{%
  \cleardoublepage
  \@mainmatterfalse
  \pagenumbering{arabic}%
}
\renewcommand{\mainmatter}{\cleardoublepage\@mainmattertrue}
\makeatother
  
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\chapter{Summary}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\chapter{Metodology}
\lipsum[2-4]\newpage\lipsum[2-4]

\backmatter

\chapter{References}
\lipsum[2-4]
\newpage
Here there is a bug in the heading. Should be only 'References' or either empty.

\end{document}
```

[image: summary]

[image: chapter 1]

[image: references]

If you really want uppercasing, remove `\nouppercase` and change the redefinition of `\chaptermark` to

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \MakeUppercase{%
      \if@mainmatter
        \chaptername\ \thechapter. %
      \fi
      #1%
    }%
  }{}%
}
```

Comment: wow, it solved the problem! thanks egreg